# how to show image in right side of text box instead of left side

Tags: css

I having a asp text box and i want to put image inside it, by below style sheet I able to put image inside textbox, but it put in left side.

Question : how to show the image in right side?

```
.watermark
 {
 background-image: url('/Images/bt_dropdown.png') ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 vertical-align: middle;
 background-color: white;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCombo" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="200" Font-Size="X-Small" CssClass="watermark"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS that would be:

```
background-position:right;
```

This looks like a usability problem though. If you're going to make a textbook look like a dropdown/combobox, users are going to expect it to behave like a combobox (like, being able to click the arrow and choose something). Are you going to be implementing some kind of JavaScript or clickable feature? If it's going to be a standard textbox I recommend avoiding any confusion with other control/input types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.username
{  
   background: #FFFFFF url(../Icon/username.png) no-repeat right;
   padding-right: 18px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```