# Show calendar control with in the textbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How to show calendar control with in the text box control in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
TargetControlID="YourTextBoxID"
Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

For more details you can see some examples from the following links:
[Calendar Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)
[ASP.NET Calendar Demo - Date picker - DatePicker/First look](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultcs.aspx)
[Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/edittemplate)

Comment: Well, But i want to show the calendar inside in textbox control,

Comment: Why don't you see [this link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx). See Default calendar. To add image in textbox use [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1514866.aspx/1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696168/how-to-show-image-in-right-side-of-text-box-instead-of-left-side)

Answer (score 2):

There is a better using native .Net tools if you have 2012 or later:
Use any textbox,go to properties and change the TextMode to DateTimeLocal.
That will create a very nice dropdown calendar.
Note: If your IE is too old it won't show the calendar, so try debug it on Chrome and Firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using the `ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit`:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
TargetControlID="TextBoxControl"
Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Alternatively you could use jQuery or some other JavaScript library such as MooTools.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Well, But i want to show the calendar inside in text box control,

Comment: @Thirisangu - yes this will achieve that.  The TargetControlID hooks it up to your texbox, so when you click inside it the Calendar displays.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Label5"
                                        Format="MM-dd-yyyy">
                                    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.